# Syntax highlighting for Python chunks does not work

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to create notebooks in which I present the same algorithm written in R and Python. I can easily integrate the R and Python code in a Rmd file and then create a HTML output using the 'Knit HTML' button in RStudio. However the Python code is always displayed without syntax highlighting (not like in the example at https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/023-engine-python.md). I have Andre Simon's highlight software installed and functioning on my computer (MacBook Pro Retina, MacOS X 10.9).

Currently, I have the following libraries installed in R: markdown 0.6.4, knitr 1.5.15, highr 0.3.1.

Any idea what could be the problem? Thanks for your help!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is specific to the RStudio Markdown render, which did not enable syntax highlighting for code blocks that are not R or C++. RStudio uses [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/), and you can use your own version of highlight.js to highlight Python code. Or use other Markdown converters such as [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Comment: Thanks! Pandoc did the trick. Now I need to learn how it works to get the result I want :-)

Comment: Can you add a simple example how to use pandoc to enable the code highlighting for a .Rmd doc containing both R and Python chuncks? I am working with Rstudio and want to enable syntax highlighting for python chuncks.

Comment: @Janvb Just use `'''py` and `'''` to include your Python code (replace `'` with a backtick, since I cannot type a literal backtick here).

Comment: @Yihui: I solved it by adding the following to the output as defined in the .Rmd in Rstudio:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
    number_sections: true
    highlight: pygments  (see https://geoscripting-wur.github.io/PythonWeek/)