# Python syntax highlighting in LaTeX in Rstudio with knitR

Tags: python, r, rstudio, knitr

How do I highlight python code in my `Rnw` files (LaTeX files)? I'm using RStudio's "Compile PDF" function to run `pdflatex`.

There are two related questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930242/syntax-highlighting-for-python-chunks-does-not-work), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520780/python-highlighting-in-rmarkdown-in-rstudio?lq=1)) for markdown files, but this questions is specific to `Rnw` files.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
print("This is R")
@

<<engine='python'>>=
print "This is python"
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to install highlight: http://www.andre-simon.de

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks @Yihui! On my Mac, `brew install highlight` did the job. Feel free to make your comment an answer. Otherwise, I'll "close out" the question by answering it myself in a few days.

Comment: Please feel free to answer your own question. PS: I'm glad you are using Homebrew, otherwise I really hate explaining how to install highlight :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install highlight: [andre-simon.de](http://www.andre-simon.de/). See @Yihui's post in the question's comments.

Comment: For those of us who aren't as competent with computers, make sure you do the following: 1) Install Highlight, as described above. 2) Add the directory in either the `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` folder where Highlight is to your `PATH` variable (see [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for example). If you already have other things in your `PATH` variable, place a semicolon before the directory. For example, I inserted `;C:\Program Files\Highlight` in my `PATH` variable. Once this is done, close any open RStudio windows, reopen RStudio, compile, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I used IPython notebook and you can [convert it to latex](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html) pretty easy.

```
$ ipython nbconvert notebook.ipynb
```

And you'll have a .tex file.