# Stata syntax highlighting in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, syntax-highlighting, bookdown

I am using Bookdown and Rmarkdown to compose a technical book for Stata users. I would like to include Stata highlighting syntax in the chunks of code, but I am not interested in actually executing Stata from Rstudio. I just want the syntax highlighting.

I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930242/syntax-highlighting-for-python-chunks-does-not-work) that it is possible to use [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/download/) but I have no idea how to include it in my .Rmd files.

I would like to be able to include something like the following and get it syntax highlighted.

````
```stata
sysuse auto, clear
reg mpg length
```
````

I highly appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get a good answer for this one?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can highlight your stata code, by using the latest R packages related to knitting.

- `rmarkdown` Ver. 2.10
- `knitr`: Ver. 1.33
- `bookdown`: Ver. 0.22

You may also have to [[u]se a Pandoc version not bundled with the RStudio IDE](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html). I use a Pandoc Ver. 2.14.0.3.

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---

- `rmarkdown`: Ver. `r packageVersion("rmarkdown")`
- `knitr`: Ver. `r packageVersion("knitr")`
- `bookdown`: Ver. `r packageVersion("bookdown")`
- (`pandoc`: Ver. `r rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`)


```stata
sysuse auto, clear
reg mpg length
```
````